# Accidentally changed user of root dir

Tags: 14.04, users, chown

I am a novice. I accidentally ran a command

`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /`

Now mysql is not working.

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Please help.

Comment: See [Ubuntu: chown of / (root) by mistake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879848/ubuntu-chown-of-root-by-mistake)

Comment: Use a live session to backup personal files if you do not have a backup and then reinstall.